# In VBA for Excel, how do I limit the following code to only run in one single Tab?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with the following Excel VBA script :

```
Sub Multi_FindReplace()
'PURPOSE: Find & Replace a list of text/values throughout entire workbook
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("Mostly satisfied", "Completely satisfied", "N/A", "Not at all satisfied")
rplcList = Array("Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Not satisfied")


'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
      Next sht
  
  Next x

End Sub
```

But the issue is that it is operating on all 3 tabs of my worksheet, when I only want it to work on one single tab - called "Refined" .

How do I change the code so that it will only loop on the "Refined " Tab ?

Do I need to remove the line `Dim sht As Worksheet` and make it to :

`Dim sht as "Refined1"` ?

Comment: Remove the `For Each` loop and add `set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Refined1")`.

Comment: @PeterT - Ok I will try this , thank you !

Comment: One would think `'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook` is clear enough...

Comment: @PeterT  - Why is it `"Refined1"` and not just `"Refined"` ?

Comment: I picked off 'Refined1' from the bottom of the OP. It could be either way, but should match his worksheet name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
'Loop through each item in Array lists
For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)

    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets '<-- This line is looping through worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next sht

Next x
```

With this:

```
Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Refined1")

'Loop through each item in Array lists
For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)

    sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

Next x
```